# Conditional using site_url is always false

Tags: expressionengine

I am trying to use the following conditional statement in my template:

```
{if "{site_url}" == "http://dev.site.com" }
    true
{if:else}
    false
{/if}
```

When I test outputting `site_url` in the template I get `http://dev.site.com`, but this expression always evaluates false.

I've tried variations without brackets and quotes with no luck.

Comment: What version of EE are you using?  This looks like a parse order issue.  Parse order was substantially updated in EE 2.9.  Current docs: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html  conditionals are parsed *before* standard global variables, BUT "As of 2.9.0 conditional tags evaluate when ready."

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Looks like we are fairly outdated -- 2.4. Any advice on a workaround for this version? We're not able to update at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a custom variable to your config.php (/system/expressionengine/config/ folder):

```
//###   Custom Variables   ###
global $assign_to_config;
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "root_url"      => $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    "domain"        => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);
```

Then change your template to be:

```
{if "{root_url}" == "http://dev.site.com" }
    true
{if:else}
    false
{/if}
```

or

```
{if "{domain}" == "dev.site.com" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might get a better answer in https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ but some ways to work around parse order issues include:

- php on input
- passing variables through embedded templates
- [low variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables)
- writing your own plugin
- exp:query calls